# sudo: system-config-printer: command not found

Tags: 18.04, printing, configuration, system, settings

I need to install a network printer. I use Ubuntu 18.04. I typed:

```
$ sudo system-config-printer
```

But I got:

```
sudo: system-config-printer: command not found
```

How can I bring the printer configuration GUI? I want to add a printer using the GUI.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy system-config-printer` to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems its not available, try installing with

```
sudo apt-get install system-config-printer-gnome
```